# Suspend Resume on PC takes forever

Tags: gnome, suspend, 19.10, pm-utils

I've recently installed ubuntu on my PC.

neofetch:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               me@My-PC
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Z390 AORUS ULTRA 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.3.0-29-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 6 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2289 (dpkg), 16 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.3 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 3840x2160 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 3.34.1 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: GNOME Shell 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-9700K (8) @ 4.900GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2204MiB / 32048MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

I've install `pm-utils` and am using `pm-suspend` (`pm-hibernate` seems to be broken. My monitor would go dark, but my PC would stay spinning. Then  I would have no way to wake it (keyboard & mouse inputs have no affect) and would have to restart completely).

The problem is, it would take about the same amount of time to resume from a suspension as it would take to boot (if not longer). There isn't any issue with persistence though (my desktop is exactly how I left it and the "There was an issue" within ubuntu wouldn't show up and no other errors).

However, before fully resuming into Ubuntu, something similar to the following would **sometimes** be displayed:

```
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000000:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x8000004c:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x8000002d:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000035:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x8000000f:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000055:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000033:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: spurious response 0x80000032:0x0, last cmd=0x4f2f02
[ *timestamp* ] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[ *timestamp* ] ata4: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ *timestamp* ] PM: dpm_run_callback(): ucsi_ccg_resume+0x0/0x20 [ucsi_ccg] returns -110
[ *timestamp* ] PM: Device 0-0008 failed to resume: error -110
```

Note: Using `pm-suspend` and `systemctl suspend` seem to have the same affect, though I use `pm-suspend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an update came along and fixed the issue ;)